# Find all tables updated on a specific date

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm using an Oracle DB, and I'm trying to find all tables that were updated on a certain date. All of the tables that track updates have a column called DT_UPDATE. I've been trying this:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'DT_UPDATE')
WHERE DT_UPDATE = <date>
```

But get this error:

```
ORA-00904: "DT_UPDATE": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 3 Column: 7
```

I've also tried aliasing the nested Select clause.

Comment: You need to use dynamic SQL, have you tried?

Comment: When I run SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'DT_UPDATE' I get a list of all tables that have a column called DT_UPDATE. Then, I want to query against all of those tables to find the ones that have a certain value in DT_UPDATE.

Comment: @zartustra, I've never tried dynamic SQL, but it looks interesting.

Comment: @9erNumber16 we got it and since your nested query (inline view) returns rows from `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` you can't limit this resultset by the `DT_UPDATE` column, because `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` doesn't have the column `DT_UPDATE`. You have to build dynamic query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @zaratustra said, you have to use dynamic SQL. You can do something like this:

```
set serveroutput on
declare
  counter number;
begin
  for r in (
    select owner, table_name
    from all_tab_columns
    where column_name = 'DT_UPDATE'
  ) loop
    execute immediate 'select count(*) from "'
      || r.owner || '"."' || r.table_name
      || '" where dt_update = :dt and rownum = 1'
    into counter
    using date '2014-07-07';

    if counter = 1 then
      dbms_output.put_line(r.table_name);
    end if;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

For each `table_name` (and `owner`, for completeness) identified in `all_tab_columns` as having a column called `dt_update`, a new dynamic select is generated, in the form:

```
select count(*) from "<owner>"."<table_name>"
where dt_update = date '2014-07-07'
and rownum = 1;
```

The `rownum = 1` filter lets the query execution stop as soon as a matching row is found; since you said you want to know which tables were updated, not how many rows or exactly which rows, if one row matches then that is all you really need to know. So for every table the dynamic query gets either 0 or 1.

For any tables that have at least one row matching the date, this printd the table name using `dbms_output`, so you have to have that enabled - with `set serveroutput on`, or with the DBMS_OUTPUT panel in SQL Developer, or your favourite client's equivalent.

If I create some tables with that column, but only populate one with the date I'm looking for:

```
create table tab1 (dt_update date);
create table tab2 (dt_update date);
create table tab3 (dt_update date);

insert into tab1 values (trunc(sysdate) - 1);
insert into tab2 values (trunc(sysdate));
```

... then running my anonymous block produces:

```
anonymous block completed
TAB1
```

Use your own target date, obviously. This assumes your date field doesn't contain a time component. If it does then you'd need to turn that into a range to cover the whole day.

You could also turn this into a pipelined function that takes a date as an argument; this also handles date fields with time elements:

```
create or replace function get_updated_tables(p_date date)
return sys.odcivarchar2list pipelined as
  counter number;
begin
  for r in (
    select owner, table_name
    from all_tab_columns
    where column_name = 'DT_UPDATE'
  ) loop
    execute immediate 'select count(*) from "'
      || r.owner || '"."' || r.table_name
      || '" where dt_update >= :dt1 and dt_update < :dt2'
      || ' and rownum = 1'
    into counter
    using p_date, p_date + interval '1' day;

    if counter = 1 then
      pipe row (r.table_name);
    end if;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Then you can query it with:

```
select column_value from table(get_updated_tables(date '2014-07-07'));

COLUMN_VALUE                 
------------------------------
TAB1
```

---

Dynamic SQL is interesting, as you said in a comment, but should only be used when necessary. The generated statement can't be parsed until it's executed, so you might not spot syntax or other errors until run-time. Also make sure you use bind variables for values (but not object names) to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: This gives me "Error report -
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
ORA-06512: at line 9
01861. 00000 -  "literal does not match format string"
*Cause:    Literals in the input must be the same length as literals in
           the format string (with the exception of leading whitespace).  If the
           "FX" modifier has been toggled on, the literal must match exactly,
           with no extra whitespace.
*Action:   Correct the format string to match the literal." It also lists 2 tables after the error report, so it may just be a problem with the setup of a table.

Comment: @9erNumber16 - `dt_update` is a `DATE` column, not `VARCHAR2`, in all the tables right?

Comment: Correct. I get the same result with zaratustra's answer. I'm unable to notice anything different between the two tables that get listed and the others that may be throwing the error.

Comment: The two tables after the error report were queried successfully and had changes that day. You can see which table it's erroring on by adding `dbms_output.put_line(r.owner ||'.'|| r.table_name)` before the `execute immediate`. You could also print the exact command it's going to execute to verify it. Might be worth checking `select table_name, data_type` from all_tab_columns where column_name = 'DT_UPDATE` does say everything really is a `DATE`?

Comment: One out of 117 results is of type CHAR. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume we have three tables with the field dt_update, and each of them has one record (doesn't matter if more):

```
create table tt1 (
  dt_update date
);
insert into tt1 values (sysdate);
create table tt2 (
  dt_update date
);
insert into tt2 values (sysdate - 1);
create table tt3 (
  dt_update date
);
insert into tt3 values (sysdate - 2);
```

This PL/SQL anonym block prints only tables' names that have record with the value of the column dt_update more than or equals today:

```
declare
  type table_names_tp is table of user_tables.table_name%type index by binary_integer;
  table_names table_names_tp;
  l_res number(1);
  l_deadline date := to_date('2014-07-08', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
begin
  select table_name
    BULK COLLECT INTO table_names
    from user_tab_columns
   where lower(column_name) = 'dt_update'
  ;
  for i in table_names.first..table_names.last
  loop
    execute immediate 'select count(*) from dual where exists (select null from ' || table_names(i) || ' where dt_update >= :dead_line)'
       into l_res
      using l_deadline;
    if l_res = 1
    then 
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Table ' || table_names(i) || ' was updated after ' || l_deadline);
    end if;
  end loop;
end;
```

You can use this code as an example to start writing your code.
 Pay carefully attention to protect yourself from SQL injections, DO NOT(!) use concatenation of your values, always use bind variables instead. It also helps you to store a cached query plan in SGA, the application will read data from the SGA area and perform soft parsing.

Comment: Thanks, this works very well! Sorry I don't have enough rep to vote it up.